# Read text from screen with OCR python

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I developed this script in SIKULI, but I would like to add more functions and I'm thinking about using Python and learning the language.
SIKULI has OCR but still contains some bugs, not performing so well. Likewise I would like to use OCR/tesseract/pytesseract in python.

The idea of ​​this script is to make you heal in a game, according to the current % of health, reading the number of the current health bar vs the total value it has.
After reading this number, a calculation is performed with the result in %.

Could you help me fix this script by inserting the necessary libraries and tweaking the code to make it work in Python?

```
#==Config HP==
Healing_1 = 95
Hk_healing_1 = '5'

Healing_2 = 65
Hk_healing_2 = '1'

Healing_3 = 30 
Hk_healing_3 = '3'

#==Code==
while True:
    GAME = App("GAME")
    GAME.focus()
    Settings.OcrTextRead = True
    
#==hp==    
    hp = Region(88,28,191,23)
    hp = hp.text()
    hp2 = hp.replace(",","")
    X = hp2.split("/")
    try:
        check_hp = float(X[0]) / float(X[1]) * 100   
    except:
        type(Hk_healing_3)
    

#==hp check==
    if check_hp < 100:
        if check_hp <= Healing_3:
            type(Hk_healing_3)    
        elif check_hp <= Healing_2:
            type(Hk_healing_2)
        elif check_hp <= Healing_1:
            type(Hk_healing_1)
    else:
        pass
```

Just for information, this function should identify the text in a region of the screen. The text of the screen, will be displayed as xxxx/xxxx (current value / total value) - it's could be other format as x/x, xx/xx, xxx/xxx, xxxx/xxxx, xxxxx/xxxxx, x/xxxx, x/xxxxxxx ...

The text will be split to perform the calculation (% of current value).